# How to create button with a link, with variable

Tags: javascript, php, html, button

I am trying to create button thats redirect me to another page.
I am trying to put variable in the link but the button isnt working.

this is my script:

```
$idSelect[i]="SELECT * FROM times WHERE id=" . $mid[i] . "";
$idResult[i]=mysqli_query($con,$idSelect[i]); 

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($idResult[i])) {
$uid[i]=$row['userid'];
}

$inc = "in.php?id=". $uid[i] ."";

echo "<input type='submit' value='back' class='button' onclick='window.location.href=". $inc ."'>";
```

**notes:**

- ID prints Int from databse.
- `echo $inc` is working, I checked it.

**I tried few tutorials, and I read answers from for the same question but they didnt help**

**EDIT:** I think my mistake is something with the onclick place, but I dont know what is the problem..

Comment: You can try anchor link instead of button.

Comment: @BindiyaPatoliya what do you mean?

Comment: you can use `type='button'` instead of `type='submit'`

Comment: @TunZarniKyaw still isnt working

Comment: if you think the error is Javascript error, then check in your browser console ... you will see what the error is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't enclose the link.

So your html output would look like this

```
<input type="submit" value="back" class="button" onclick="window.location.href=in.php?id=1">
```

so javascript will look for a variable called `in`

This should work

```
echo "<input type='submit' value='back' class='button' onclick='window.location.href=\"". $inc ."\"'>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
$inc = "http://in.yahoo.com/?p=us";
echo "<input type='submit' value='back' class='button' onclick='redirect()'>";

echo ("<script>
function redirect(){
    window.location.href = '$inc';
}
</script>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey use **onclick='window.location.replace'** as below-

```
echo "<input type='button' value='back' class='button' onclick='window.location.replace="'. $inc .'"'>";
```